# end of file unexpected (expecting ")"), passing a command to git filter-branch

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

Hello I've made a script to capitalise commiters names and change their email

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter \
'export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$( sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<< $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME) \
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<< $GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL) \
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$( sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<< $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME) \
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<< $GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL) \
git commit-tree "$@"'
```

the sed commands, when run by themselves, work but as a whole it throws

```
Rewrite e3acbe28d660ffc6ef8e9a5a79ba9bd24c3b48bd (1/22)git commit-tree:48:
git commit-tree: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
could not write rewritten commit
```

Comment: Be careful with those single quotes, especially when using them nested!

Comment: Exactly that -- single quotes don't nest. When you put a single quote inside a single-quoted string, it just ends the quote that started the string and enters an unquoted context.

Comment: Yep, no doubt you're opening and closing your string mid-way through those `sed` commands. Better way to do it would be `git filter-branch --commit-filter << EOF commands EOF`. The `EOF` method doesn't rely on quotes to open and close the string to be used as an argument (this is all assuming you're running this with `bash` or `sh`)

Comment: Yes as it's an argument for git

Comment: Oh wow you're right, big blunder on my part.

Comment: You all saw nothing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single-quotes inside your `export` commands are being read as syntactic, not literal.

One way to fix this is to set your command string in a quoted heredoc, and expand it later:

```
cmd=$(cat <<'EOF'
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")
git commit-tree "$@"
EOF
)

git filter-branch --commit-filter "$cmd"
```

`<<'EOF'` is used to prevent expansions inside the heredoc from being processed *before* its assignment.

Note that the `export`s are gone -- the shell automatically exports any update to a variable already present in the environment, and exporting it to the environment before starting a shell is exactly how `git filter-branch` ensures that the values are available in the first place.